# Getting a small part of the dataset from Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, machine-learning

I am trying to access the Enron Email dataset from Amazon (http://aws.amazon.com/datasets/917205) for a Machine Learning project I am working on. I need a small amount of data to write my Map Reduce code before I can run that over the entire dataset. But the file is 210GB in size. How can I extract a small part of the file to write and test my MR jobs with?

Thanks for any pointers/suggestions.

-S